# Parking Spots Availability Design

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a reservation table that has `from_date`, `to_date`, and `parking_location_id`. What is the best way to calculate location spots availability for each location and each hour?

I tried to write a query that calculates availability from reservation table but this query is very slow when the period is long even though the `from_date` and `to_date` columns are indexed.

Another approach to speed things up was to create a location availability table

[image]

The contains all locations and all dates and hours in a range of years and whenever a reservation is saved a trigger updates the reserved spots in this table. However, in this approach, the table rows size grows exponentially and we need to add a range of dates with location ids whenever a new location is added. Any ideas how can I improve this design or what alternatives do we have?

The slow query tries to calculate number of reserved spots per date and then we find the max number in that date range.

```
select  sum(r.number_of_slots) as reserved_spots
from location l 
inner JOIN reservation  r on r.location_id=  l.id  , time_dimension t
where t.db_date between r.from_date and r.to_date and 
 t.db_date < r.to_Date and t.db_date > r.from_date  t.id=type_id and group by db_date;
```

Time dimension table contains a list of all dates in 10 years.

Comment: Which table are `from_date and to_date` in?  (Please add aliases.)  Also `db_date`.

Comment: So, that is a subquery with `ORDER BY reserved_spots DESC LIMIT 1` in the outer query?

Comment: @RickJames I aliases to query. I don't have order by in the query not sure what do you mean?

Comment: It seems you used the alias `t` for `time_dimension` and for `location`?

Comment: You didn't specify: what is the granularity of your `db_date` table? Is it every hour?

Comment: yes it is every hour

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use a calendar or schedule table.

In my example I've set up a 3-day table calendar with intervals of one hour:

(Do a google search to find out some date series generator, you'll find a lot)

```
    Hours table
===================
2017/01/01 00:00:00
2017/01/01 01:00:00
2017/01/01 02:00:00
2017/01/01 03:00:00
2017/01/01 04:00:00
2017/01/01 05:00:00
...
...
```

Then simply LEFT JOIN your table with the calendar table and get NULL rows:

```
    Hours table               Reservations
===================        ===================
2017/01/01 00:00:00        2017/01/01 00:00:00
2017/01/01 01:00:00  LEFT  2017/01/01 01:00:00
2017/01/01 02:00:00  JOIN  NULL                 <-- Free
2017/01/01 03:00:00        2017/01/01 03:00:00
2017/01/01 04:00:00        NULL                 <-- Free
2017/01/01 05:00:00        NULL                 <-- Free
```

> ```
> SELECT    hdate 
> FROM      calendar
> LEFT JOIN reservations
> ON        hdate = from_date
> WHERE     parking_id is null;
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=d904a98871d9b2c258980a6db42a61b9)*

Comment: The reservation has from_date and to_date so it is a range. As far as I can see, your solution only uses from_date. Can we improve this to work on a  time range?

Comment: You said granularity is one hour, If you want I can add one hour to hdate just to show the range.